# Spring jdbcTemplate executing query

Tags: oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have a strange problem ,
My Query looks like below.

```
String tokenQuery = "select id from table
                      where current_timestamp between
                 creation_time and (creation_time + interval '10' minute) 
                   and token = '"+Token+"'";
```

But when I run, `jdbcTemplate.queryForLong(tokenQuery)` , no matter what , it always throws EmptyDataAccessException. 
I am executing this in Oracle
Can we not append dynamic values to string and then pass it as a query and execute ?
What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you get is in fact an EmptyResultDataAccessException. The javadoc of this exception says:

> Data access exception thrown when a result was expected to have at least one row (or element) but zero rows (or elements) were actually returned.

That simply means that the query is executed fine, and is supposed to return one row, but doesn't return any. So no row satisfies the criteria of your query.

If that is expected, then catch the exception, or use a method that returns a list rather then returning a single value. That way, you can test if the returned list is empty.

That said, you should use a parameterized query instead of concatenating the token like you're doing. This would prevent SQL injection attacks. It would also work even if the token contains a quote, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Infact If I run the same query(which I copy  while debugging ) directly using sqldeveloper, it returns me one row and one column. That is what is perplexing me . Is it the single quote or is it that queryForLong() works in a different way than expected ?

Comment: I would check the token first. Are you sure it's capitalized correctly. Are you sure it doesn't have any trailing white space, etc.